# Excel How to reference a cell then add an offset to its formula (if possible)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am not sure if this possible or not, basically trying to reference a cell's formula then add an offset of 1 to it (the image below may explain it better).

[image: Img to help understand the problem]

I've tried formulatext > indirect > offset(ref,1,0) but it didn't seem to work.

offset direct doesnt work.

Thanks :)

Comment: In your example in the image, if you just take the formula from G1 and drag / copy it down to G2, it gives you your desired result.

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes that does work as a manual solution. Is there a way to automate this e.g. if A1 is selected 100 will show in G2?

Comment: @Chris Can you try this `=MAP(B1:B2,D1:D2,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))` formula?

Comment: It's becoming more unclear - are you saying that you want the result of the formula in G2 to change, just by selecting different cells, without changing any data? And in your example if A1 is selected, how would you calculate 100 in G2, what numbers are you using to get to 100?

Comment: @Harun24hr This does work, however, it is static to b1b2 and d1d2. Looking for a solution that is dynamic with whatever the user enters into G1

Comment: You have written "B1+1", do you mean "20 + 1" (value of B1 is 20), or do you mean "B(1+1)" which is B2, which equals 100? In latter case, you can just drag the formula in H1 down to H2, you'll see that the formula in H1 stays "=B1+D1" while in H2 you get "=B2+H2".

Comment: @kevin the numbers in the image are random, imagine a user has put =A1+C1 in G1, G2 would then automatically get this then increase the Row by x (in this example 1) which would be =A2+C2.

Comment: @Dominique thanks for your help, sorry I mean by 1 row (B2). Yes, the dragging method works, however, looking for a solution that dynamically updates G2 from the G1 value of A1+B2 to A2+B2.

Comment: @Chris: the current formula inside G1, you claim this to be A1+B2 or A2+B2, but I believe it's A1+A2. Which one is it?

Comment: @Dominique Sorry G1 (A1+B1) G2 (A2+B2)

Comment: @Chris: ok, and which formula do you want in which cell?

Comment: @Dominique In G1, the user will choose from A1 to D1 using the formula =X1+Y1. My goal is for G2 to automatically adjust the formula in G1 by one row, becoming =X2+Y2.

Thus, following the original post's example, =B1+D1 in G1 will be translated to =B2+D2, resulting in a value of 300.

Comment: @Chris: I've provided you with a VBA solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily, using VBA:

```
Sub test()
  Range("G1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G1:G2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

This will take the formula in "G1" and apply it over the range "G1:G2", which is the same as dragging the "G1" formula towards "G2".

Answer (score 1):

You could use this formula:

```vb
=LET(f,$G$2, d,A3:H3,
formula,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(f)," ",""),"=",""),
parts,TEXTSPLIT(formula,"+"),
SUM(INDEX(d,,COLUMN(INDIRECT(parts)))))
```

It expects a formula in G2 that includes multiple cell-references joined by a +-sign.

The formula excerpts the single cell-references and retrieves the column index of each cell reference. Column index is then used to return the single values of the row.

[image]

Comment: @P.b How does your formula in G2 look like?

Comment: My bad, I had the formula in G1 and forgot to reference that. This also works: `=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(G1),{"+","="},,1),SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(a),1,)))`

Answer (score 0):

Would OFFSET(B1,1,)+OFFSET(D1,1,) do the job?
Or slightly more expandable...
=OFFSET(B1,ROW()-1,)+OFFSET(D1,ROW()-1,)

I'm unsure what you mean by "Whatever is selected in G1 is then calc+1 in G2"

Comment: Imagine a user has put =A1+C1 in G1, G2 would then automatically get this then increase the Row by x  (in this example 1) which would be =A2+C2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since I noticed in your comments to Inkca (not in the question itself) you wanted to use offset because you wanted to be able to change the offset of rows from the referenced cells in your sum, I wanted to share this option as well:

```
=LET(shift, 1,
     b,TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(G1),{"+","="},,1),
SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(b),shift,)))
```

This way you can easily change the number of shift to change the offset.

You could also reference a cell that holds the `shift` value, for instance `G2`:

```
=LET(shift, G2,
     b,TEXTSPLIT(FORMULATEXT(G1),{"+","="},,1),
SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(b),shift,)))
```

[image]

Tip for future questions is to better formulate the goal of your question. Note the many questions as a result of the question itself.